# Build Jabbr SignalR Chat

Tags: c#, signalr, chat, jabbr

When I try to build the Jabber project I get this error:

[a Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0h7P.png)!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is need more information. Show your work. Tell people what have you tried. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: I have tried nothing, the project doesn't build. thats the only issue

Comment: Do you have NuGet Package manager installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already, make sure your source for the project is up to date.

https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR

Also, make sure package restore for NuGet is enabled (**Tools > Options > Package Manager**). You may also consider clearing your Package Cache.

I downloaded the source just now. I had to enable package restore but after doing that it built fine.